# Why is my code leaving an item off of the list on every case?

Tags: c#

I am working on this training video. I noticed in my example below that my code leaves the last item out of the list every time. It worked before I made the code more fancy and readable.

**Question: Why is my code leaving the last item off?**

```
SortedDictionary<string, SortedSet<Employee>>
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private void printDictionary(Dictionary<string, List<Employee>> InputDictionaryParm1)
        {
            foreach (var a in InputDictionaryParm1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.Key);
                foreach (var e in a.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + e.Name);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var d = new DepartmentCollection();

            d.AddDept("AA", new Employee { Name = "L" })
             .AddDept("AA", new Employee { Name = "A" });

            d.AddDept("BB", new Employee { Name = "D" })
             .AddDept("BB", new Employee { Name = "E"} )
             .AddDept("BB", new Employee { Name = "F"} )
             .AddDept("BB", new Employee { Name = "A"} );

            d.AddDept("CC", new Employee { Name = "J" })
             .AddDept("CC", new Employee { Name = "Z" })
             .AddDept("CC", new Employee { Name = "X" })
             .AddDept("CC", new Employee { Name = "Y" });

            d.AddDept("DD", new Employee { Name = "T" })
             .AddDept("DD", new Employee { Name = "W" })
             .AddDept("DD", new Employee { Name = "E" })
             .AddDept("DD", new Employee { Name = "A" });

            foreach (var a in d)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(a.Key);
                foreach (var e in a.Value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + e.Name);
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            //printDictionary(d);
        }
    }

    public class EmployeeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employee>, 
                                    IComparer<Employee>
    {
        public EmployeeComparer() { }

        public bool Equals(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            return String.Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Employee obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        }

        public int Compare(Employee x, Employee y)
        {
            return String.Compare(x.Name, y.Name);
        }
    }

    public class DepartmentCollection : SortedDictionary<string, SortedSet<Employee>>
    {
        public DepartmentCollection()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DepartmentCollection");
        }

        public DepartmentCollection AddDept(string d, Employee e)
        {
            if (ContainsKey(d))
            {
                this[d].Add(e);
            }
            else
            {
                Add(d, new SortedSet<Employee>(new EmployeeComparer()));
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Screen Shot:

[image]

Comment: looks like a missing call to `this[d].Add(e);`

Comment: You should favor composition to inheritance.  Rather than extending `SortedSet`, `DepartmentCollection` should really wrap a `SortedSet`.  As it is you are exposing the internals of the collection, allowing it to be manipulated without using your own add method that maintains certain properties about the collection (namely that each inner set is non-empty).  These properties can be violated when you expose everything about the set publicly.

Comment: A quick glance would have shown the missing one isn't the last one in order, but the first one added..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `AddDept` method doesn't actually add the value if the key is missing:

```
    public DepartmentCollection AddDept(string d, Employee e)
    {
        if (ContainsKey(d))
        {
            this[d].Add(e);
        }
        else
        {
            Add(d, new SortedSet<Employee>(new EmployeeComparer()));

           // Add this!
           this[d].Add(e);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Note that you can reverse the conditional to simplify this code:

```
    public DepartmentCollection AddDept(string d, Employee e)
    {
        if (!ContainsKey(d))
        {
            Add(d, new SortedSet<Employee>(new EmployeeComparer()));
        }

        this[d].Add(e);
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. I had looked at that for almost 30 minutes and had not seen that myself.